# Improving on the decoding of a .dat file

Tags: c, fread

I'm writing the program that is supposed to do a zero suppression on 3000+ .dat files of 500 MB each, on a Windows machine with 46 logical cores and 128 GB of RAM. I'm using 30 threads, so every thread will have to work with 100+ files. The first step is decoding the .dat files created by a digitizer, for that I've been given a C source file with something like this:

```
out_file=fopen(output_file.txt, "w");
ptr_myfile=fopen(Data_0.dat, "rb");

uint32_t nwords = 0;
int16_t wfm_adc;

i=0;
offset=0;
while(i<NSAMPLE){
            fseek(ptr_myfile,offset,SEEK_SET);
            fread(&nwords, 4, 1, ptr_myfile);
            wfm_adc = (int16_t)(nwords & 0xFFFF);
            fprintf(out_file, "%d\n", wfm_adc);
            i++;
            wfm_adc = (int16_t)((nwords & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
            fprintf(out_file, "%d\n", wfm_adc);
            i++;
            offset = offset + 4;
}
```

From what I understand it reads 4 bytes of data at a time and writes 2+2 bytes in the file.
The data in the output file look something like this

```
-96
-139
-115
-143
-119
-188
-408
-1355
```

It works fine, the only issue is it's very slow, there are about 250 million samples and it takes roughly 250 seconds to just read the data from a file, without even writing to file with fprintf, so as each thread has to decode 100+ files it will take 25000 seconds per thread just for that. 
Is there a way to improve this? I've read that by reading more data with fread, instead of 4 bytes say 64Kb, there would be less overhead from calling the fread, but I haven't found a way to then get the data that I need and write it to the file.

Comment: Just remove seeking file each read and you'll get a lot more speed. Reading 4 bytes at time there is no need to seek again the same 4 bytes. Moreover seeking a file is a very slow action. Don't worry about reading more at time, the buffered IO is already helping you (the fread/fwrite family).

Comment: Pretty sure you could save some time by using one `fprintf` instead of two

Comment: @Frankie_C thanks, it's 3 times faster now!

Comment: To make it much more faster try to open concurrent files on different disks. Having 30 threads and 46 cores waiting for the same resource, the same disk unit, is equivalent to a single core.